# What's the centre of mass of a rod with varying density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

The density of a linear rod of length L varies with the distance x from one end as d=kx where d is density and k is constant. Locate the centre of mass of the rod.

I tried it many times and messed up in integration getting L/2. Please help

Comment: Hi Shivanshu and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: sorry but can u suggest where i can ask such questions

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is essentially the analogoue of the weighted mean:

$\frac{\int_0^L r\cdot \rho(r)dr}{\int_0^L \rho(r) dr}$

It is named first moment. Intuitively, we can say, actually we sum up the infinitesimal small $dr$ parts of the rod, and we make a weighted average value between their distance from the 0 point.